# How to embed lua scripts as Resource File (*.rc) on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, lua, embedded-resource

The title of the question kind of says all of it.
But, to be more precise: I have this C++ application and want to be able to import lots of *.lua script files (over a hundred) as resource so they won't be available and visible on my release.

My goal is obfuscating them INSIDE my app.exe.

Comment: Consider [User-defined Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054(v=vs.85).aspx) with LoadResource or EnumResourceEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting the files to `base64` stream and saving them as a `const char` in a `header` file. Works for me. Everything gets compiled within the exe. Plus I have the multi-platform advantage.